# problem with IN clause in SQL

Tags: sql

We have observed that there seems to be a maximum number of ids/variables which one can pass in the IN clause of SQL as comma separated values. To avoid this we are storing all the ids in a table and doing a SELECT within the IN clause. This however means extra database operations to store and retrieve ids. Is there any other way to use IN without SELECT?

Regards,

Sameer

Comment: What database server are you using? The answer depends on this data.

Comment: SQL server 2007 and Oracle 10.2

Answer (score 2):

In `SQL Server 2008` you can declare a table variable and pass it to your query from the client or between the procedures.

Comment: The query i have is in HQL (hibernate query language) embedded in j2ee code. Also this needs to work with oracle 10.2 as well. Not sure this will work

Answer (score 2):

For a modest number of values I would not have thought an `IN (SELECT ..)` would be that expensive on any rdbms.

You could `INNER JOIN` you IDs table or just break down the INs:

```
WHERE X IN (123,456 ...)
   OR X IN (789,987 ...)
   ...
```

Comment: I already have the variables. Using your example
WHERE X IN (123,456 ...) 
   OR X IN (789,987 ...) 
123,456 etc are already in variables. But i cannot list all 12,000 of them as there is a limitation to this. I am trying to avoid making another database hit for a save and then a select

Comment: 12,000?! how are you passing them to an in clause(s)?

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Alex

Instead of

```
Select * From TableA Where ID IN (Select ID from IDTable)
```

Use

```
Select * From TableA
INNER JOIN IDTable ON TableA.ID = IDTable.ID
```

The join will automatically filter the IDs for you.

Comment: @Quassnoi Thanks for the link to the in depth article. In the OPs case, they are storing the IDs in a table, so I was just pointing out that the JOIN way was going to be equivalent if all they are doing is filtering. Also, 9 times out of 10 if i have a choice I'll use the join method for readability and style reasons. It's also worth noting that an IN with comma separated values gets expanded to a bunch of ORs when it is actually processed.

Comment: @Jemery: `IN` with comma separated values expands to a `CONSTANT SCAN` when a certain threshold of values is hit. The values are regarded as a table subject to normal set-based operations (hash join, merge join etc).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that! Do you have any idea what the threshold is, or does it vary according to the query? The reason I ask is because I've worked on projects where stored procedures receive a comma separated list of values from SSRS parameters. I went through the work to parse the string and put the IDs in a temp table in order to join to it. I'm thinking this was still a good idea, because the user could have chosen just 1, 2, or everything in the parm list. The other reason we wen through the trouble is that I think we would have had to use dynamic SQL if we just wanted to use the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it in atable why are you still using the in clause, why not just join to the table?

Comment: Sure i could do that. The main thrust of my question is NOT to store ids in a table. I already have those Ids in variables, but since there is this limitation on number of variables one can pass into an IN query, i am forced to store the ids in a table (extra database hit) and retieve (using JOIN or IN) (another db hit